# Asus A6vm не работает аудиовыход

Tags: ubuntu, аудио, ноутбук

Доброго времени суток. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой. Через встроеные динамики звук отличный, но когда подключаю наушники или колонки звука к сожалению нет. На разных форумах много всякой инфы но ничего не помогает.И через микшеры тоже ничего.У меня убунту 10.04звуковая карта intel ALC880

Answer (score 1):

Знаешь, похоже это кирдык гнезду, ибо там чисто механическое переключение.Для проверки попробуй запуститься с какого-нибудь Алкида (на Зере есть, например). Он большинство звуковых карт понимает, и если в динамиках звук есть а на колонках нет - меняй гнездо (работа копеечноя даже в сервисе)